# How to save a variable created in interactive mode?

Tags: python, pycharm

So, if you create a new project in pycharm and then an empty.py file, and run it in interactive mode (editing the interpreter settings), ">>>" will appear (which I don't know exactly what it is, but this not the question, the question is that if you write "print (" something")", then the console will print that, and if you write "a = " something" " and then "print (a) ", the console will print a, if you stop running the file and run it again and try to print a again, it will appear that it is not defined.

What I want to know, is how do I save(in the file) this variable before stopping to run the file, so that after I run it again I can access it.

Comment: You could pickle it

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using pickle. Pickling basically saves your object to a file. For example:

```
import pickle
a = 5
with open('pickle.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(a, f)
```

This should create a file "pickle.pkl". Now, if you want to load it:

```
import pickle

with open('pickle.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    a = pickle.load(f)
print(a)
>>> 5
```